# Notification in android app

Tags: android, notifications

I need to notify my android app if any changes made by php database, actually we dont want to use push notification to notify as it device based,  any other way to get notification? please give some idea.

Comment: try using syncadapter class. i never used it but i know that it is used for the purpose that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a service which will stay in background always and that service will implement to a weblistener interface, so that whenever you change the db in php and send some response to your phone and the interface will listen to your response.

Comment: that depends on the service which you will create, if the service is using the wifi or any other thing which is battery exhausting, then it might drain your battery pretty quick, better to use push notification rather than running a service in background continously.

Comment: Ok,  Can i implement push notification based on the mobile number or user id instead of Device Id?

Comment: You can surely implement push notification without being dependent on device id, please search for push notification examples in google you will get many.